# If $C(K)$ is isomorphic to $C(H)$, are $K$ and $H$ homeomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $K,H$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. The Banach Stone theorem says that $K$ and $H$ are homeomorphic $\iff$ $C(K)$ and $C(H)$ are isometrically isomorphic. Is it true that if $C(K)$ and $C(H)$ are just isomoprhic, that $K$ is homeomorphic to $H$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K$ and $H$ are both uncountable, then by Miljutin theorem (see [theorem 4.4.8 in *Topics in Banach space theory by Fernando Albiac, Nigel J. Kalton*](https://books.google.ru/books?id=UG6zDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=Miljutin%20theorem%20continuous%20function&source=bl&ots=q1kItj7ORX&sig=ACfU3U1vwdIj31DZK6rRsc6camj1qMCauA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibgrKd58ThAhXw-SoKHaoHCpwQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Miljutin%20theorem%20continuous%20function&f=false)) $C(K)$ and $C(H)$ are isomorphic.

Thus there is an abundance of counterexamples: take any two uncountable topological spaces that are not homeomorphic, say $K=[0,1]$, $H=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$.

As for countable compacts, see [*S. V. Kislyakov. Classification of spaces of continuous functions of ordinals. Siberian Mathematical Journal, 1975, Volume 16, Number 2, Page 226*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00967506)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and references!

Answer (score 2):

If K is the unit circle,  and H is the unit interval,  I think you can construct an explicit isomorphism between C(K) and C(H)  by sending trigonometric polynomials to ordinary polynomials and vice versa. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem,  the above rule defines an isomorphism.